# Couldn't find the specific details for a IBM x3850 server

Tags: cpu, motherboard, webserver

[This](http://www.gumtree.com.au/s-ad/thornlie/desktops/ibm-x3850-server/1044002353) ad mentions the model of the server as " IBM x3850-[88633SM]- ". However, in my searches I was unable to find any meaningful reference to the specific server. The closest I could find is [this](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/au/x/hardware/enterprise/x3850x5/specs.html) reference, that I do not believe to be the same model.

The ad also says that the server has 6 NIC cards but, as stated earlier, I couldn't find a picture or any other information, particularly regarding the rack unit of the server.

Can anyone please throw some light on what model that is

Comment: I've added the link you gave in comment to the body of your question. I also reformatted your question a little, trying to maintain the original meaning. In the future, try to edit your question instead of adding more information via comments; this way, this question is bumped to the top page, giving it more attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a System x3850 Type 8863 system. I found a [System x3850 Type 8863 Installation Guide](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/systems/support/system_x_pdf/31r1853.pdf) which provides some diagrams and indicates (page 16) that the Xeon processors have 1 MiB of L2 cache and 667 MHz front-side bus and the system uses DDR2 memory. This seems to indicate a Nocona-based Xeon, the first 64-bit Xeon, released in 2004.

The size is indicated (also page 16) to be 3U, weight: "approximately 38.5 kg (85 lb) when fully configured or 31.75 kg (70 lb) minimum".

This system is only four sockets, but the seller might be counting the virtual processors as CPUs (Nocona-based Xeon had two-way multithreading, a.k.a. hyperthreading).

I have not found anything indicating what the "3SM" means, but [this page at IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?infotype=an&subtype=ca&htmlfid=877/ENUSZG06-0376) related to a newer model has a small table that shows -**?**SG (with **?** being 1, 2, 3, or 4) used for different processor bins (different frequency, cache size, or the like), so presumably 3SM refers to such details.